# Website continuously shaking due to typer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

As you can see, [the website I made](http://geekfysiek.lucasdebelder.be/#The%20Club) always moves up and down like it's getting triggered/intensify on the 'The Club' section.

It has something to do with the [typer.js effect](https://steven.codes/typerjs/) -- mainly the `span .cursor`:

```
<div class="bubble1">
    <span class="typer" id="main" data-words="Vandaag lopen?" data-colors="white" data-delay="100" data-deletedelay="1000" style="color: white;">Vanda</span>
   <!-- THIS ONE KILLS IT--> <span class="cursor" data-owner="main" style="transition: all 0.1s; opacity: 0;">_</span>
</div>
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before as well? And how did you fix it?

My only way to fix it so remove the `span .cursor` but then the text balloon/bubble gets empty, how can I get around that? I've uploaded a [second example here.](http://lucasdebelder.be/stack/index.html#The%20Club) Although that fixes the shaking effect which is more irritating then the empty balloon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't want the bubble to change size when there is no text. So why not set a height for the bubble?

Comment: Yes that does the job, thanks. But tbh I want to keep the white horizontal line